# Running React Native / Expo in docker container not hot reloading

Tags: node.js, react-native, docker, expo

I am trying to setup my Expo / React Native in a docker container to test it out. Some of it seems to work, the Expo Developer Tools loads on my local machine, but when I edit the App.js it doesn't update the app. I have installed chokidar, but that doesnt seem to work either.

My Docker file is as follows;

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yq curl && \
  curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY . /home/
WORKDIR /home

RUN npm install && npm install chokidar && npm install -g expo-cli && npm i -g yarn
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and my docker-compose.yml looks like so;

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  expo_app:
    container_name: expo_app
    build: .
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    environment:
      - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

I am running it all using `docker-compose up -d` ... Once it boots up, i can see the Expo Develop Tools, but editing files just doesnt work.

Has anyone had any success in running this stack and have all the issues ironed out?

Comment: What host OS are you using?

Comment: @HansKilian . My host machine is a Mac (Intel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mount your current directory to /usr/src/app when you run the container, but the workdir in the container is /home.

Change the mount point to /home by changing your docker-compose file to

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  expo_app:
    container_name: expo_app
    build: .
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    environment:
      - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - .:/home
```